# Do accidentals apply to other staffs of the same type?

Tags: notation, sheet-music, accidentals

In this excerpt from Bach's BWV 772, does the B flat accidental on the lower staff also apply to the upper staff(second to last beat)?

I know that accidentally usually do not apply to different staffs, but these have same clef. Does the accidental on the upper staff not need to be notated in this case?
[image: bwv772]

Answer (score 5):

As Dom states, each and every stave is a separate entity, and accidentals need to be put in for each changed note. 
This is in D minor (at least here), and what's happening is the normal melodic minor trick of that era. Melodies going downwards would use a natural minor configuration, while those rising would have a raised 6th and 7th. Thus, Bbs in the left hand, as the tune drops, but the right hand tune rises with a B natural and C# (sharpened earlier in that bar).

Answer (score 3):

In deciding whether an accidental should be printed, one should generally expect that people reading music will be blind to staffs that don't contain their part(s), and *may* be blind to music which they are not performing even when it shares a staff with music they are; one should add cautionary accidentals if necessary to ensure that such possible blindness will not affect the pitches to be performed.

In your example, a keyboard piece in C major has two treble clefs, and the left hand (lower staff) plays a mid-staff B♭ near the start of a measure, then if the right hand plays that same staff note later in the measure it should be explicitly marked with either ♭ or (♮).  Indeed, such a marking should be used in cases where the staffs used different clefs (e.g. if the left hand, notated with bass-clef, played the F♯ above middle C, and then the right hand, notated with treble clef, played its first-space F.

Note also that if e.g. in C major one performer performs a B♭ in the middle of treble clef, and another performer *simultaneously* performs a B♮ in the middle of treble clef, it may be helpful to mark the latter note with a cautionary accidental (♮).  Such a marking may not be necessary from a performance standard, but in its absence the dissonance might make performers wonder if the "B♮" might be actually be a misprinted B♭.  In cases where confusion is unlikely, no accidental is required, but when confusion would otherwise be likely, a cautionary accidental can help.

Returning to your example, the B♭ shouldn't apply to the right hand, but I think that notationally it would have been appropriate to mark the right hand B with a (♮).

Comment: +1. Printers/writers are pretty keen to remind us that a bar line cancels an accidental (by printing the cancelling accidental that referred to the previous bar) - totally unnecessary - so in this case of POSSIBLE confusion, why not put another accidental? Personally, I'm all for uncluttered music.

Comment: @Tim: My philosophy is that notation should be generally chosen to maximize the likelihood of accurate interpretation, even while sight-reading, and an editor should use judgment as to what things might be misinterpreted.  I would consider cautionary accidentals appropriate in many situations where there would be no particular "rule" calling for them, but a lot depends on judgment.  For vocal music, or for instruments where performers play "relative" pitches, I favor parentheses around cautionary accidentals to help performers judge whether a note is higher or lower than what they'd "expect".

Answer (score 2):

No they do not.  If you wanted to represent the accidental on a different staff you would need to write it in. Each staff is independent of the other even if they are linked as in your example.

Answer (score 2):

No, accidentals are *always* staff independent.

The reason you have a Bb in at the beginning of the bar and a B natural at the end is because the Bb is pulling down to the A and the B natural is leading up to the C.