# Do accidentals last for the entire measure?

Tags: notation, accidentals

When I mark a note with an accidental, is that accidental gonna be applied to that note for its duration or is it applied every time that same note is played in that same measure?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The accidental will apply to following notes in the same measure / bar but not after that.  If it is needed to cancel the effect before then another accidental (maybe a natural sign) will be required.

Oddly, although a sharp or flat in the key signature affects the same note in other octaves, an accidental does not.

An extra point thanks to Arthur. In the case of a tie across bar lines, it also lasts for the remainder of that tie (but not to the rest of the second bar).

And thanks to Guy G, note that odd exceptions may occur.  Some older manuscripts may expect that the accidental applies to other octaves.

Comment: In the case of a tie across bar lines, it also lasts for the remainder of that tie (but not to the rest of the second bar).

Comment: I agree that accidentals don't affect other octaves, but I've seen several older manuscripts where they should have.  I don't know whether this is because they are lower quality scores (generally they are), or because the rule was different / non-standardised in the past.

Comment: @GuyG Odd things happen.  I have one manuscript in which the key signature appears on the opening bar but it is not repeated on each line as usual. I coped but it confused one of my friends considerably.

Comment: @Arthur That's a good point.

Answer (score 3):

Same staff line (or space) for the entire measure.

Comment: For the *remainder* of the measure.

Comment: From where they appear for the remainder. Thanks. Also, unless overridden by another accidental on the same staff line or space.